# How to divide the result of two different queries in SQL?

Tags: sql, division

Query number 1:

```
SELECT starting_location, count(starting_location) as POPULARLOCATION
FROM trips
GROUP BY starting_location
ORDER by POPULARLOCATION DESC
```

Query number 2:

```
SELECT starting_location, count(starting_location) as CIRCULARTRIP
FROM trips
WHERE starting_location = ending_location
GROUP BY starting_location
ORDER by CIRCULARTRIP DESC
```

I want to find out what % of trips are circular trips for each starting location. How do I divide the result of the 2nd query by the result of the 1st query?

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and a tag for the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

one way is like so:

```
SELECT starting_location
  count(*) as POPULARLOCATION
, count(case when starting_location = ending_location then 1 else null end) as CIRCULARTRIP
, count(case when starting_location = ending_location then 1 else null end) * 100.00 / count(starting_location)  as percentage
FROM trips
GROUP BY starting_location
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but do you think that it’s possible to do this question with the JOIN function? By simply joining the two queries together and then dividing?

Comment: why would you do that , it makes it unnecessarily more complicated and slow

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional aggregation.  To get the ratio, I think the simplest method is:

```
SELECT starting_location,
       COUNT(*) as POPULARLOCATION,
       AVG(CASE WHEN starting_location = ending_location THEN 1.0 ELSE 0 END) as circular_ratio
FROM trips
GROUP BY starting_location
ORDER by POPULARLOCATION DESC
```